# I need to wrap each element of an array even the children elements, I'm working with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, recursion, wrapper

I need to wrap each element of an array, even elements of the children.

input:

```
var array = [
{"name":"name1"},
{"name":"name2"},
{"name":"name3", children : [{"id":"1"}]}];
```

Desired output:

```
var newArray = [
{elem : {"name":"name1"}},
{elem : {"name":"name2"}},
{elem : {"name":"name3", children : [{elem : {"id":"1"}}]}}];
```

I have done the following:

```
function insertKey(array){
    for (var i = 0; i<array.length; i++){
        tempItem = {elem : array[i]}
        newarray.push(tempItem);
    }
}
```

// Output:

```
 newarray = 
[{elem:{"name":"name1"}},
 {elem:{"name":"name2"}},
 {elem:{"name":"name3"}}]
```

But the problem comes when it contains children. I tried the below but its not working.

```
function insertKey(array){
    for (var i = 0; i<array.length; i++){
        tempItem = {elem : array[i]}
        newarray.push(tempItem);
        insertKey(array[i]);
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show an example of the input and the desired output?

Comment: The most obvious problem is that the recursive call needs to be inside the loop, so that it can use `i`.

Comment: And it probably should be `insertKey(array[i].children)`, or you need to test if `array[i]` is an array before recursing.

Comment: input:
var array = [
{"name":"name1"},
{"name":"name2"},
{"name":"name3", children : [{"id":"1"}]}];

output
var newArray = [
{elem : {"name":"name1"}},
{elem : {"name":"name2"}},
{elem : {"name":"name3", children : [{elem : {"id":"1"}}]}}];

Answer (score 1):

To do this for any level of nesting, we can use a fairly simple recursive approach:

```js
const transform = (xs) =>
  xs .map (({children, ...rest}) => ({
    elem:  {
      ...rest,
      ...(children ? {children: transform (children)} : {})
    }
  }))
```

But I think one level of abstraction improves this significantly.  If we separate the bit that wraps a node in an `{elem: ...}` structure from the bit that recursively applies that, our code is both simpler and more reusable.  Its concerns are better separated.  So I would probably write it like this:

```js
const mapDeep = (fn) => (xs) =>
  xs .map (({children, ...rest}) => fn ({
    ...rest,
    ...(children ? {children: mapDeep (fn) (children)} : {})
  }))

const data = [
  {name:"name1"},
  {name:"name2"},
  {name:"name3", children : [
    {id: "1"}, 
    {id: "2", children: [ {foo: "bar"}, {foo: "baz"} ]}
  ]}
]

const wrapInElem = (node) => ({elem: node})

console .log (mapDeep (wrapInElem) (data))
```

And of course by passing only the function to `mapDeep`, we get a reusable function that does what you want:

```js
const transform = mapDeep (wrapInElem) 
// or, using an anonymous function instead 
// const transform = mapDeep (node => ({elem: node})) 
// ...
transform (data)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try iterating over each object of array and adding them to new array. That gives the output that you desire.
define the function as:
    -

```js
function f(array){
newArray=[]
for(i of array){
newArray.push({elem:i})
}
return newArray
}

var array = [
{"name":"name1"},
{"name":"name2"},
{"name":"name3", children : [{"id":"1"}]}];

newArray=f(array)
console.log(newArray)
```

Comment: Note that this does not wrap the children as desired.  `children: [{id: 1}]` versus the requested `children: [{elem: {id: 1}}]`.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want something like this:

```js
function insertKey(array) {
    const newarray = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        const tempItem = {elem : array[i]};
        if (array[i].children) {
            tempItem.children = array[i].children.map(child => ({elem: child}));
        }
        newarray.push(tempItem);
    }
    return newarray;
}
```

The new conditional maps each child and wraps it like you described. You'll use this like so:

```js
const newarray = insertKey(array);
```

Edit: Note that this solution only works for one level of nesting. If you needed it to go deeper, your question (as stated) doesn't give us enough information to help, because we don't know the schema of the data that you're trying to wrap.